# Python: read from file into list

Tags: python, file-io

I want my program to read from a .txt file, which has data in its lines arranged like this:
`NUM NUM NAME NAME NAME`. How could I read its lines into a list so that each line becomes an element of the list, and each element would have its first two values as ints and the other three as strings?

So the first line from the file: `1 23 Joe Main Sto` should become `lst[0] = [1, 23, "Joe", "Main", "Sto"]`.

I already have this, but it doesn't work perfectly and I'm sure there must be a better way:

```
read = open("info.txt", "r")
line = read.readlines()
text = []
for item in line:
    fullline = item.split(" ")
    text.append(fullline)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without an argument to have whitespace collapsed and removed for you automatically, then apply `int()` to the first two elements:

```
with open("info.txt", "r") as read:
    lines = []
    for item in read:
        row = item.split()
        row[:2] = map(int, row[:2])
        lines.append(row)
```

Note what here we loop *directly* over the file object, no need to read all lines into memory first.

Comment: I think doing `row.strip().split()` would help

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: No, because `.split()` with no arguments (or `None` as the first argument) already *does* that.

Comment: I had no idea. Thank you!

Comment: Works like charm, thank you. I came from codecademy, could you recommend something I could learn more from about Python? (to be able to do things like your answer on my own)

Comment: Keep reading Python stuff, keep coding. There are [loads of resources](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FrontPage#start) to keep you going. I cannot recommend anything more specific; I've been coding Python for 15 years now, it has been too long since I picked up any Python books.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file) as f:
    text = [map(int, l.split()[:2]) + l.split()[2:] for l in f]
```