# How to use pubmed_lookup with url to crawl?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file which contains many different url.
like this,

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24297623
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23857717
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18166110
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23635779
```

And I also found the guideline in pubmed-lookup 
like this,

```
from pubmed_lookup import PubMedLookup
email = ' '
enter code here
url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22331878'
lookup = PubMedLookup(url,email)
```

So how can I do to read so many urls in my file in order to get the information at once?

Comment: Why can't you just loop the urls and fetch them one by one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: read from file into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137942/python-read-from-file-into-list)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the urls in a list and loop through them.

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
   urls = [line.strip() for line in f]

lookup = []
for url in urls:
    lookup.append(PubMedLookup(url,email)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help!!